# TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to run a basic CNN on using macOS Anaconda.
All Keras ati is up to date (atleast i think so, but im sure it is)

I am able to run everything except for when i need to run this line,

```
classifier.fit_generator('training_set',
                     steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                     epochs = 25,
                     validation_data = test_set
```

When i attempt to run that i get the error,

TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator

This is my code,

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/Dan/Desktop/CNN/dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/Dan/Desktop/CNN/dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator('training_set',
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)

# Saving Weights
weights = classifier.save_weights

"""
Single Prediction
"""
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image


test_image = image.load_img(('dataset/predictions/cat_or_dog_2.jpg'), target_size=(64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'Dog'
else:
    prediction = 'Cat'
```

And this is the code itself running up to the error,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
Using TensorFlow backend.
2019-11-25 19:39:19.093497: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2019-11-25 19:39:19.095093: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 4. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/Dan/Desktop/CNN/dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')
Found 8000 images belonging to 2 classes.

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/Dan/Desktop/CNN/dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.

classifier.fit_generator('training_set',
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)
Epoch 1/25
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-e4696e5027ff>", line 5, in <module>
    validation_steps = 2000)

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 185, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 742, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 696, in reraise
    raise value

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 711, in get
    inputs = future.get(timeout=30)

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))

  File "/Users/Dan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 650, in next_sample
    return six.next(_SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid])

TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

Is there something i am missing? or a line that is wrong because im sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a string as a first argument, you want to pass the training_set variable.

```
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with the package, but checking the documentation it shows that training_set should be a generator:

> generator: A generator or an instance of Sequence
>   (keras.utils.Sequence) object in order to avoid duplicate data when
>   using multiprocessing. The output of the generator must be either
>   a tuple (inputs, targets) a tuple (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
>   This tuple (a single output of the generator) makes a single batch.
>   Therefore, all arrays in this tuple must have the same length (equal
>   to the size of this batch). Different batches may have different
>   sizes. For example, the last batch of the epoch is commonly smaller
>   than the others, if the size of the dataset is not divisible by the
>   batch size. The generator is expected to loop over its data
>   indefinitely. An epoch finishes when steps_per_epoch batches have been
>   seen by the model.

But you are using a string with value 'training_set', I'm guessing you mean training_set (without quotes).
https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Comment: ah yes thank you that solves the error, but now the code runs but only starts at 1/25 epochs (and even that doesn't run through), no error is shown and the code just moves to a new line.